# How to automatically pre generate thousands of ETH addresses for my app users

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapps, myetherwallet

I'm building an app where every user will have app-generated ETH Wallet to do transactions with internal ERC20 Tokens.

I would like to pre-generate wallets for my users, and assign every wallet upon signup to users.

How can I automatically create let's say 100,000 ETH accounts, and keep the information on my database (address, keys, etc)

Thanks, any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

On first look, this is an anti-pattern.

In summary, it looks like confusing authentication with privilege and internal organization. The pattern goes against the natural organization of the platform and will likely lead to non-trivial difficulties.

**The natural way.**

You will presumably need authentication and access control. The good news is that all users are authenticated and you can reliably know the address they used to sign a transaction.

You can use that as the basis for identifying users and controlling access to sensitive functions. E.g. some accounts, like the account your server is using, get special privileges.

Examples:

Balances of all (100,000+) users that will ever exist:

```
mapping(address => uint) userBalances;
```

Access control:

```
require(msg.sender == ownerAddress, "You are not the owner.");
```

Under no circumstances would you ever divulge the server's signing key or ask the users to do that.

**The unnatural way.**

1. Create 100,000 accounts and signing keys with a script.
2. Create data on the chain for 100,000 accounts (at your expense).
3. Server switches personnas for each transaction.
4. Contract is unaware and does not disclose the server's special status.

**TL;DR;**

It's better form and more transparent to favor:

- from: Server, transaction concerning a certain user and other arguments

over

- from: User (actually the server signing but this fact is significantly obfuscated)

To say it another way, there is no improvement over a fully centralized process when the server has signing keys for each user.

Hope it helps.